# How do I associate individual buttons with individual divs?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a web page where I have a list of buttons, and each button toggles the visibility of a div directly below it.

The problem I am having is that all of my buttons only toggle the visibility of the last div in my page.

Here is the following relevant code:

HTML

```
<div class="menuItem">
    <button>Food Item</button>
    <div class="info">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <img src="../images/menu/spaghetti.jpg" alt="spaghetti">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">
    <button>Food Item</button>
    <div class="info">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <img src="../images/menu/spaghetti.jpg" alt="spaghetti">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">
    <button>Food Item</button>
    <div class="info">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <img src="../images/menu/spaghetti.jpg" alt="spaghetti">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
"use strict";

(function() {
    var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");

    for(var ii = 0; ii < menuItems.length; ii++) {
        var button = menuItems[ii].getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
        var info = menuItems[ii].getElementsByClassName("info")[0];
        button.onclick = function() {
            if(info.style.display === "block") {
                info.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                info.style.display = "block";
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

I don't think I totally understand what the javascript is doing under the hood. I think I'm getting references to each individual button, but it seems like when I change the onclick method for one button, I am changing the onclick method for all of them. Why is this happening, and how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, this is simple:

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

I added ' class="toggle" ' to each button. Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/tx4tsvfa/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **jQuery** to do so. 
You can define a function (let's call it `toggleInfo` and put it in onclick attribute like so:

```
<button onclick="toggleInfo()">Food Item</button>
```

And then in your function you can use `.toggle()` on the nearest element with class `info`

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `info` within `click` handler using `.nextElementSibling`

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");

  for (var ii = 0; ii < menuItems.length; ii++) {
    var button = menuItems[ii].getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    button.onclick = function() {
      var info = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (info.style.display === "block") {
        info.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        info.style.display = "block";
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuItem">
  <button>Food Item</button>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <img src="../images/menu/spaghetti.jpg" alt="spaghetti">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">
  <button>Food Item</button>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <img src="../images/menu/spaghetti.jpg" alt="spaghetti">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">
  <button>Food Item</button>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <img src="../images/menu/spaghetti.jpg" alt="spaghetti">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Event Delegation**

There is a much simpler way to do that. Add a parent container

```
<div id="container">
<div class="menuItem">
.....
```

Create a custom Click handler for the parent container

```
function handler(e){
 console.dir(e.target);//maybe console.log(e.target);
 // or console.dir(e.target.parentNode);
}
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click',handler,false);
```

Check console while you click. there are many useful informations about the clicked element's and it's parentNode

---

In your case:

```
function handler(e){
 if(e.target.nodeName=='BUTTON'){//if i click on the correct element
   e.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('info')[0].classList.toggle('view');
 }
}
```

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) [nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

here is the custom hide class.

```
.view{
 display:none;
}
```

I also would avoid `display:none` the browser needs to redraw the whole element everytime.think of `top:-999999px; opacity:0; height:justthebuttonsize; transform:scale(0);`

The cool part of this is that you have only one Event! No loops! And many more advantages. You don't even need `document.getElementsByClassName` if you navigate trough the nodes (which is much faster).Ahh and this is everything pure native javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/z6kk5rxc/2/

if you don't understand something just ask